# How to finding a zip dependency path?

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

In my SBT build, I'm fetching a zip dependency (previously built with the sbt-native-packager plugin), published in my local Ivy repo with a `bundle` classifier.

But I need the dependency path in the Ivy repo, in order to unzip it (with `IO.unzip`), put some files in it and repackage it with sbt-native-packager.

I'm using the `artifacts(...)` method to find the artifact and add it as a dependency :

```
"foo" % "bar" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT" artifacts(Artifact("bar-bundle", "zip", "zip", "bundle"))
```

But after that, I'm a bit lost...

I tried to filter out the `dependencyClasspath` to find it :

```
val bundleFile = taskKey[File]("bundle's path")

val settings = Seq(bundleFile <<= dependencyClasspath map { _ filter (_.endsWith(".zip"))})
```

Trouble is : I can't find the zip dependency in any classpath... 
What I'm doing wrong ?

I'm using sbt 0.13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zip files aren't on the classpath by default.  The types of artifacts that are included are configured by `classpathTypes`.  You can add "zip" to it with:

```
classpathTypes += "zip"
```

It will then appear on `dependencyClasspath`.

However, if it isn't really supposed to go on the classpath, you might pull it out of the update report directly.

```
bundleFile := {
   val report: UpdateReport = update.value
   val filter = artifactFilter(name = "bar-bundle", extension = "zip")
   val all: Seq[File] = report.matching(filter)
   all.headOption getOrElse error("Could not find bar-bundle")
}
```

See the documentation on [UpdateReport](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Detailed-Topics/Update-Report.html) for details.